# Stop screen dimming after 60 seconds - Ubuntu on a MacBook Air

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, macbook-air

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a MacBook air - everything works fine, apart from the fact that the screen dims after 60 seconds of activity.  Is there any way to stop this?

My computer is on mains power.  If I stop using the machine, after 30 seconds the keyboard backlight turns off (that's fine).  After a minute, the screen dims by about 50% - this is *annoying*, especially when watching a video or reading a long page of text.

My "brightness and lock" settings seem fine:

[image]

I've tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-time 600
```

But that doesn't make a difference - it still dims after 60 seconds, no matter what value I set it to.

I've also used `gconf-editor` but I don't appear to have `/apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight`

I'm not using Unity - just the standard Gnome desktop.

Is there any way to change this behaviour? I **never** want my screen to dim.  I'm quite happy controlling it manually with the F1 and F2 keys.